# snapshot from video url using javascript

Tags: javascript, video, snapshot

I need to get snapshot image from video stream URL using JavaScript.
I need to display video's "thumbnail" in html div.

I need to do it using JavaScript dynamically.
Please let me know if any ideas.

Comment: Where is the video coming from? What format? Some services such as Youtube provide thumbnails automatically.

Comment: video is an rtmp link. I need to capture a thumbnail in img format so that I can place it in a div.

Comment: @user3174598 RMTP link is external? See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By javascript is not possible.

---

If your video is in your server will be possible only using [FFMPEG](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video), eg.:

`ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:14.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png`

---

If your video is an RTMP then you can use the [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) for save the video in your server, after use ffmpeg.

```
rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://[stream_address] -o 1.flv
```

---

If video is in Youtube, you needed server-side (php, c#, jsp) and should handle this type urls (in php use `curl`):

Thumbnail Image, Small (120x90):

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/1.jpg`

Thumbnail Image, Small (120x90):

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/3.jpg`

Default Thumbnail Image, Small (120x90)

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/2.jpg`

Default Thumbnail Image, Full-Size (480x360):

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg`

Source: [How To Download A Thumbnail Image From YouTube](http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/)

in this case you can even use javascript and canvas, but in webkit browsers causes a problem of "taint" (it is actually a safety lock)

---

If the video is on another server will not be possible.

Comment: Thank you for this. For now, I just went ahead and streamed the video by default instead of keeping a thumbnail reference.